# Powershell Where-Object excluding a result

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I just wrote a small script to give me a list of all folders in my music library, that don't include an Artist.nfo or Album.nfo.

My folder structure is like: M:\Genre\Artist\Album

The Artist.nfo should be located in the Artist, and the Album.nfo in the Album folder.

As I'm searching for both of the files seperately, I'm now struggling to exclude the other .nfo in the search result.

My current search functions:

```
#region noArtistnfo
function noArtistnfo
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param ($path)
    Get-ChildItem $path -recurse | Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer -eq $True }`
    | Where-Object { $_.GetFiles().name -notcontains "Artist.nfo"}`
    | Select-Object FullName | Out-String
}
#endregion noArtistnfo

#region noAlbumnfo
function noAlbumnfo
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param ($path)
    Get-ChildItem $path -recurse | Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer -eq $True }`
    | Where-Object { $_.GetFiles().name -notcontains "Album.nfo" } | Select-Object FullName | Out-String
}
#endregion noAlbumnfo
```

I already tried the following, but that's not giving me any results:

```
Get-ChildItem $path -recurse | Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer -eq $True }`
        | Where-Object { $_.GetFiles().name -notcontains "Artist.nfo"}`
        | Where-Object { -! $_.GetFiles().name -contains "Album.nfo"}`
        | Select-Object FullName | Out-String
```

What am I missing here?
Can you tell me how to exclude the folders if there's one of the .nfo's already present?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you're going to be able to exclude those folders. What I would suggest is finding all of the Artist.nfo and Album.nfo files, and compare their parent folder to a listing of all folders, and the difference should be what you are looking for.

So get all folders, save in a variable. Get all the Artist.nfo and Album.nfo objects, and then do a `Select -ExpandProperty Directory` on the results and save that in a second variable. Then do a `Compare-Object` on them to find the folders missing nfo files.

```
$AllDirs = Get-ChildItem M:\* -recurse -directory
$NFOFound = Get-ChildItem M:\* -Include "Artist.nfo","Album.nfo" -recurse | Select -Expand Directory
Compare-Object $AllDirs -DifferenceObject $NFOFound -Property FullName | Where{$_.SideIndicator -eq "<="}
```